# In async grpc server is there a way to measure the time a request has spent in the completion queue?

Tags: grpc

We have an async grpc c++ server and we'd like to get stats about how long a request has spent in the completion queue before it has been picked up by an application. Is there a way to get this stat in grpc?

Answer (score 0):

No, gRPC C++ doesn't have metrics for that.